# How to call Xib file from NSObject to display as a common view in all ViewController in the iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nstimer, xib

I want to create a XIB for commonly as i call from app delegate or NSObject class via timer then it will show depend on timer.

Any help?

Comment: Write a method in NSObject's subclass which will have one parameter for target for which you will send your viewControllers instance while calling the method and inside the method you can display the popUp or whatever the view you want to display on the target instance.

Comment: could u create some sample for me ?

Comment: I can just help you with the code you have tried. Have you subclassed UIView for the view you want to show on multiple screens?

Comment: Yes please can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method that will show the content of xib Views with code

For example:

```
- (UIView *) createView
{
        UIView *rootView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyRootView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        return rootView;
}
```

This method return view from xib file and you can call this method with timer from delegate or nsobject class whereever  you want.

Comment: button action not called in nsobject class